# Akka Remote actor selection with configuration

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Is there a way for setting configuration for remote actor **selection** simliar to the remote actor **creation** as specified in [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html):

```
akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
      /sampleActor {
        remote = "akka.tcp://sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I prefer not to define custom variable for that.

```
system.actorSelection("sampleActor")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two forms of the actor selection method, from the docs:

> def actorSelection(path: ActorPath): ActorSelection
>
> Construct an akka.actor.ActorSelection from the given path, which is
>   parsed for wildcards (these are replaced by regular expressions
>   internally). No attempt is made to verify the existence of any part of
>   the supplied path, it is recommended to send a message and gather the
>   replies in order to resolve the matching set of actors.
>
> def actorSelection(path: String): ActorSelection
>
> Construct
>   an akka.actor.ActorSelection from the given path, which is parsed for
>   wildcards (these are replaced by regular expressions internally). No
>   attempt is made to verify the existence of any part of the supplied
>   path, it is recommended to send a message and gather the replies in
>   order to resolve the matching set of actors.

And an ActorPath is just created from a string anyway:

> def
>   fromString(s: String): ActorPath
>
> Parse string as actor path; throws java.net.MalformedURLException if unable to do so.

So there isn't a direct way to do actor selection just by setting a particular value in config. However it is quite easy to pull a value from config and use it for actor selection. Given the config:

```
akka {
  actor {
    selections: {
      sampleActor: {
        path: "akka.tcp://sampleActorSystem@127.0.0.1:2553/user/sampleActor"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could use:

```
val sampleActorSelection = 
  system.actorSelection(
    system.settings.config.getString("akka.actor.selections.sampleActor.path"))
```

If this was a method you found yourself using frequently, you could use an implicit class to add a helper method to system:

```
implicit class ActorSystemExtension(system: ActorSystem) {

  def actorSelectionFromConfig(actorName: String): ActorSelection {
    system.actorSelection(
        system.settings.config.getString(s"akka.actor.selections.${actorName}.path"))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But how is that diffrenet from using custom variable ?

Comment: It's not very different at all. The short answer to your question would be "no there isn't a way" but I thought a more comprehensive answer would be more useful.